# To create the time period column

Tags: date, tabular

I have the data where the date is given but has not the own column, because the first column is `AAPL.High`, but when I do `view(data)` I see that the first column is time period column. I need to select and sort my `data` by year. But how can I do that if this column does not exist or how to add the time period column?

```
                    AAPL.High AAPL.Low AAPL.Close AAPL.Volume A
2015-06-01 13:30:00 131.31    131.39   130.95     18342
2015-06-01 13:35:00 131.00    131.01   130.63     11334
```

Comment: Please tell us what system you are using so the correct expert can answer.

Comment: I use Windows 10 or what did you mean?

Comment: We still don't know what this question is about. What on Windows 10? Is it some package or language you are using. What  thing do you want help with?

Comment: I want to select the two samples from this data by using format=%Year. But to do that, I need to have the column with the time period, but I have not this column in my data because the first column is AAPL.High. However, When I view this data I see the time (in the left of the table), but it has not the separate column in my data

Comment: Is this about using the language R?